# loop through serialized file

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I'm working on a school assignment that is supposed to open a serialized file and output it. I can't figure out why it isn't printing anything. It doesn't seem like the loop is working at all. Any ideas?

```
public ReadFile()
{
    try
    {
        fis = new FileInputStream("Clients.ser");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            //cast according to class Record
            r = (Record) ois.readObject();
            System.out.print(r.account + r.firstName + r.lastName + r.balance);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) { ioe.printStackTrace(); }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {}
}
```

**Edit**

Added a stacktrace to `IOException` and it returned:

> `Record; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 5124020354301486787, local class serialVersionUID = -8881068308941519505`

- [`ReadFile.java`](http://pastebin.com/CXipee6i)
- [`Record.java`](http://pastebin.com/8Ha4BuyT)

Comment: Log your exceptions, at the very least.

Comment: What do you get? exception? have you tried to debug the code line by line?

Comment: Put a System.out.print inside each of the empty catch(...) {} blocks. And then run again. Then tell us the output.

Comment: Put a print inside the catches, caught `IOException`.

Comment: Can you show the code that calls this code?  Are you doing this work in a constructor (as it appears above)?

Comment: @ChrisKnight Indeed. I updated with the complete code.

Comment: I suggest that you start by debugging your code with System.out.println() calls or a debugger. Also, you are silently ignore some exceptions. At the very least, you should print out a meaningful message when an error occurs.

Comment: @Code-Guru Added messages. The second `IOException` is thrown.

Comment: @ChrisKnight Changed the first and it did not print anything; the second one did.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk Now you should print out the stacktrace to find out *why* an exception is thrown. This will also tell you what line throws the exception.

Comment: @Code-Guru Added a stack trace. Posted output in question. Not sure what that means.

Comment: Try adding ``static final long serialVersionUID = 5124020354301486787L;`` to Record.java

Comment: @ChrisKnight Looks like the class that was writing it was `private` and now is `public`. Thanks for your help all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That message means that the class you are trying to deserialize is not the same as the class you specified.

Were you given the Record class by whoever serialized it, or did you write it yourself?

Comment: Just figured this out. Indeed the class that serialized it was `private` and the deserialized class is `public`. Also, if you have a question in your answer, it's best to ask it in the comments; not in your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the reputation for that.

Comment: My apologies; should have known. In that case; thank you for your suggestion and question.